# Google Sheets Query with Logic Statements

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language, google-sheets-query

I am trying to create a list of data from a data range in Google Sheets. I thought of using the query function, but with that, you can't seem to use regular logical statements.

I know that this snippet of code is wrong and doesn't work, but hopefully it makes it clear what I'm trying to do.

```
=Query(E2:E103, OR(AND(D2:D103=A$2,G2:G103=A$5),AND(D2:D103=A$3,G2:G103=A$5),D2:D103=A$1))
```

In this code, `A$2`, `A$5`, `A$3`, and `A$1` are all just string variables in the corresponding cells that tell the logic statement what to compare.

If there is another way to write this or a different function that accomplishes what I would like to do, it would be greatly appreciated if you could share it with me.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51800828/multiple-if-statements-with-a-drop-down-google-sheets-query/51806103#51806103 for an example of building up the logic within the string of the SQL rather than with functions.

Comment: so you want to select E WHERE (pseudocode here, not sql) (d matches A2 and G matches A5) or (D matches A3 and g matches A5) or (D matches A1)? Because you for sure one can build such a query.

Comment: One key is to remember to ampersand in the single quotes around the strings to which you are comparing. Looking at your statement, it looks like it could be shortened to (D matches A1) or ((g matches A5) AND ((D matches A2)OR(D matches A3))). So like Query(d2:g103,"Select * WHERE (D='" & $A$1 &"') OR ..."

Answer (score 1):

## Basic case

The basic syntax for building a query logic:

`"where F = '" & A1 & "'"`

- assumes A1 is a string, values in column F are strings
- adds single quotes, makes the resulting query string: `where F = 'sample text'`

## Logic

Your case looks like this:

`where (A) or (B) or C` =>

`where (A1 and A2) or (B1 and B2) or C` =>

`where (D = 'text1' and G = 'text2') or (D = 'text3' and G = 'text4') or D = 'text5'`

Comment: I wrote this function per your suggestion, `=Query(E2:E, "Select  * Where ((D = 'text1' and G = 'text2') or (D = 'text3' and G = 'text4') or D = 'text5')")`, but now I'm getting an error that reads "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: D". I assume that it means I need to include column D in my query, but in my case, I only want column E to be outputted and not D and E or everything in between.

Comment: The first parameter in QUERY has to include all pieces that go into the query (so D2:G). IF you only want some to come out, that is where you would say SELECT E WHERE.... Very well explained @Max Makhrov , I like how you taught the principles not just gave code.

Comment: Please try `=Query(D2:G, "select E where..."`